# Change Default App Name and Icon from Inside App?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am from Myanmar, here military is arresting the people who installed VPN app in the phone. I developed VPN app and released on the stores for both iOS and Android with flutter.
In case,I want to add App's customize feature (Change App name and Icon) inside my App.
Does anyone know how can I achieve this case with Flutter.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rename

Comment: changing the app icon at run time is only supported for IOS check this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon

Comment: @K_Chandio I just want to change inside App after installed.